# How can I reduce allocation for lookup in C++ map/unordered_map containers?

Tags: c++, boost, unordered-map

Suppose I am using `std::unordered_map<std::string, Foo>` in my code. It's nice and convenient, but unfortunately every time I want to do a lookup (`find()`) in this map I have to come up with an instance of `std::string`.

For instance, let's say I'm tokenizing some other string and want to call `find()` on every token. This forces me to construct an `std::string` around every token before looking it up, which requires an allocator (`std::allocator`, which amounts to a CRT `malloc()`). This can easily be slower than the actual lookup itself. It also contends with other threads since heap management requires some form of synchronization.

A few years ago I found the *Boost.intrusive* library; it was just a beta version back then. The interesting thing was it had a container called `boost::intrusive::iunordered_set` which allowed code to perform lookups with any user-supplied type.

I'll explain it how I'd like it to work:

```
struct immutable_string
{
    const char *pf, *pl;
    struct equals
    {
        bool operator()(const string& left, immutable_string& right) const
        {
            if (left.length() != right.pl - right.pf)
                return false;

            return std::equals(right.pf, right.pl, left.begin());
        }
    };

    struct hasher
    {
        size_t operator()(const immutable_string& s) const
        {
            return boost::hash_range(s.pf, s.pl);
        }
    };

};

struct string_hasher
{
    size_t operator()(const std::string& s) const
    {
        return boost::hash_range(s.begin(), s.end());
    }
};

std::unordered_map<std::string, Foo, string_hasher> m;
m["abc"] = Foo(123); 

immutable_string token; // token refers to a substring inside some other string

auto it = m.find(token, immutable_string::equals(), immutable_string::hasher());
```

Another thing would be to speed up the "find and insert if not found" use case—the trick with `lower_bound()` only works for ordered containers. The intrusive container has methods called `insert_check()` and `insert_commit()`, but that's for a separate topic I guess.

Comment: Use a better library implementation? It's possible to implement `std::string` such that small strings never use any dynamic memory allocation...

Comment: If `std::string` is too expensive, wrap your own object around the token and avoid heap allocation. Intrusive vs non-intrusive containers is an orthogonal issue.

Comment: @BoPersson: still, libstdc++ does not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to lexing, I personally use two simple tricks:

1. I use `StringRef` (similar to LLVM's) which just wraps a `char const*` and a `size_t` and provides string-like operations (only const operations, obviously)
2. I pool the encountered strings using a bump allocator (using lumps of say 4K)

The two combined is quite efficient, though one need understand that all `StringRef` that point into the pool are obviously invalidated as soon as the pool is destroyed.

Comment: As of Boost 1.53, you can use `#include <boost/utility/string_ref.hpp>`

Comment: Very good, thanks. I can't upgrade to Boost 1.53 for my present work. Anyway I'm making use of `unordered_map<immutable_substring, Foo>`. Essentially it's the only realistic option that doesn't involve tinkering with the interface for containers. my `immutable_string` really amounts to the same thing as `StringRef`.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out `boost::unordered_map` (as of 1.42) has a `find` overload that takes `CompatibleKey`, `CompatibleHash`, `CompatiblePredicate` types, so it can do exactly what I asked for here.